# Get previous value in for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<DELVRY07>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                <EXIDV>123</EXIDV>
                <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VHART_BEZ>SSCC Box</VHART_BEZ>
                    <MAGRV_BEZ>All materials</MAGRV_BEZ>
                    <VEBEZ>BOX - Parcel Express</VEBEZ>
                </E1EDL38>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                <EXIDV>123</EXIDV>
                <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VHART_BEZ>SSCC Box</VHART_BEZ>
                    <MAGRV_BEZ>All materials</MAGRV_BEZ>
                    <VEBEZ>BOX - Parcel Express</VEBEZ>
                </E1EDL38>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                <EXIDV>456</EXIDV>
                <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VHART_BEZ>SSCC Box</VHART_BEZ>
                    <MAGRV_BEZ>All materials</MAGRV_BEZ>
                    <VEBEZ>BOX - Parcel Express</VEBEZ>
                </E1EDL38>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
        </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
```

Where I want to remove all E1EDL37 segments which have the same EXIDV value as the previous one:

```
<DELVRY07>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                <EXIDV>123</EXIDV>
                <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VHART_BEZ>SSCC Box</VHART_BEZ>
                    <MAGRV_BEZ>All materials</MAGRV_BEZ>
                    <VEBEZ>BOX - Parcel Express</VEBEZ>
                </E1EDL38>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
            <E1EDL37 SEGMENT="1">
                <EXIDV>456</EXIDV>
                <E1EDL38 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VHART_BEZ>SSCC Box</VHART_BEZ>
                    <MAGRV_BEZ>All materials</MAGRV_BEZ>
                    <VEBEZ>BOX - Parcel Express</VEBEZ>
                </E1EDL38>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000010</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000020</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
                <E1EDL44 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VELIN>1</VELIN>
                    <VBELN>3030043338</VBELN>
                    <POSNR>000030</POSNR>
                </E1EDL44>
            </E1EDL37>
        </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
```

I tried this with the following XSLT conversion, but this will eliminate all E1EDL37 segments:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <DELVRY07>
        <IDOC BEGIN="1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//EDI_DC40"/>
            <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                <VBELN><xsl:value-of select="/DELVRY07/IDOC/E1EDL20/VBELN"/></VBELN>
                <BTGEW><xsl:value-of select="/DELVRY07/IDOC/E1EDL20/BTGEW"/></BTGEW>
                <GEWEI><xsl:value-of select="/DELVRY07/IDOC/E1EDL20/GEWEI"/></GEWEI>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//E1ADRM1"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//E1EDT13"/>   
            <xsl:for-each select="/DELVRY07/IDOC/E1EDL20/E1EDL24">
                <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
                    <xsl:variable name="position" select="."/>
                    <POSNR><xsl:value-of select="POSNR"/></POSNR>
                    <MATNR><xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/></MATNR>
                    <ARKTX><xsl:value-of select="ARKTX"/></ARKTX>
                    <LFIMG><xsl:value-of select="LFIMG"/></LFIMG>
                    <EAN11><xsl:value-of select="EAN11"/></EAN11>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="E1EDL41"/>

                    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>                                                                      
                    <xsl:variable name="preceding-group-member" select="current-group()[$pos - 1]"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="this-data" select="E1EDL37/EXIDV"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="preceding-data" select="$preceding-group-member/E1EDL37/EXIDV"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$this-data != $preceding-data">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="E1EDL37"/>
                    </xsl:if>

                </E1EDL24>
            </xsl:for-each> 
            </E1EDL20>
        </IDOC>
    </DELVRY07>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't figure out why this is and I've been searching for a solution several hours now. Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this using templates :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="E1EDL37[EXIDV=preceding::E1EDL37[1]/EXIDV]"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4Jk

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** to detect duplicates, similar to the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="E1EDL37" use="EXIDV" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove duplicate E1EDL37s -->
<xsl:template match="E1EDL37[not(count(. | key('k1', EXIDV)[1]) = 1)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution is also working great, but I am able to understand why Sebastien's solution works. Therefor I decided to go with his solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-adjacent`, and then select the first in the group

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="E1EDL37" group-adjacent="EXIDV">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to work when the `E1EDL37` nodes are not siblings.

Comment: Seems you spent longer making sense of these cryptic element names than I did!